# JQuery Ajax help

Tags: jquery

I am creating a portfolio page for m personal site. I have a slider with a bunch of anchors that relate to projects I have worked on, each one contains a client logo that when clicked should load a html page into a div on the same page. I would like to use JQuery to achieve this my question is which method would I use load() or ajax(). This is not something I have done before so I'm a little confused what the difference is.

Also if it makes any difference to my question I will be making the site content managed with MODX very soon.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load()` is just a shortcut for `ajax()` method with certain options. If you only need to fetch page and place it in the dom you can use `load()` method. If you need more control over the ajax request or you need to call it with some other options then go for `ajax()`

Comment: @Giorgi I do want to fetch and place the page, ideally I'd like to wait until it loads then fade the page in, would this be a job for ajax()?

Comment: @mtwallet ajax() is for controlling the fetching itself and not animations. You can pass callback to load() which will be executed once the request completes.

Comment: one last question if I may. Would I have to use unload() first  to ensure the div I am placing content into is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you to understand and implement different ways of making Ajax request on jQuery:

[6 Different Ways to Make Ajax Request via jQuery](http://blog.kshitizgurung.info/2011/03/6-different-ways-to-make-ajax-request-via-jquery/)